# ElasticSearch Updating Document

Tags: elasticsearch

General help question, but I wanted to ask a clarifying question on how updating documents in ES works.

When adding a document request to the elasticsearch indexing, do we have to include all fields for that document or just the ones I want to update?

If there already exists a document with the same document id, would our new document request override all data in that document or just update the fields listed in this document request? In other words, do I need to supply all the fields in this document request or just the ones I want to update? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html):

> The update API also supports passing a partial document, which is
> merged into the existing document.